# Why is doccker using cached mysql data instead of latest mysql dump?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker image for mysql datbase.

The first time I made this work I backed up my db to a .sql file and then from my docker-compose I
build up the dabase.

Now however I have made some updates, created a new .sql file and again through the docker-compose I thought I would get my new data and new changes.

my docker-comose file:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE # CAP_SYS_NICE
    # container_name: my_very_special_server
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wedding
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SomeRootPassword1!
      MYSQL_USER: someuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Password1!
    volumes:
      - ./dbScript/Dump20201018.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Dump20201018.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dev_pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80
  server:
    container_name: weddingapp_server
    build: ./weddingApp-Be
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    links:
      - mysql
    command: npm run dev
  client:
    container_name: weddingapp_client
    build: ./weddingApp-Fe
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db_data:
```

After the build was finished and I spinned it up I saw that my new data wasn't showing up, I still had the old data cached somewhere?

I checked the logs for my mysql image and got this:

> 2020-10-18 20:46:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for

> MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started. 2020-10-18 20:46:59+00:00

> [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql' 2020-10-18

> 20:46:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server

> 8.0.21-1debian10 started. 2020-10-18T20:46:59.686360Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as
> process 1 2020-10-18T20:46:59.693458Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB]

> InnoDB initialization has started. 2020-10-18T20:46:59.987115Z 1

> [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

> 2020-10-18T20:47:00.115947Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin

> ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket:

> /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock 2020-10-18T20:47:00.196070Z 0 [Warning]

> [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

> 2020-10-18T20:47:00.196193Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel

> mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now

> supported for this channel. 2020-10-18T20:47:00.200913Z 0 [Warning]

> [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location

> '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider

> choosing a different directory. 2020-10-18T20:47:00.219538Z 0 [System]

> [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version:

> '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL

> Community Server - GPL.

I am fairly new to docker and honestly I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

initdb scripts are only executed when your data directory (`/var/lib/mysql`) is empty.

Your data are not cached, but persisted to your host using your volume. So if this is a development work, you can simply delete the contents of `db_data` volume (or deleting and creating it again):

```sh
docker volume rm db_data
docker volume create db_data
```

Comment: User docker volume prune

Comment: When you wrote `- db_data:/var/lib/mysql` in your compose file, you mapped a volume in your host (`db_data`) to a filesystem path in your container (`/var/lib/mysql`). You just need to `docker volume rm db_data && docker volume create db_data` to recreate this volume and make it clean.